# If condition in a Comprehension list with Nan(s)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, list-comprehension, nan

I have a dataframe with two date columns, and I am trying to get the delay, in working days, between them. These columns contain NaN values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date1' : [np.nan, np.nan, "2021-05-26", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-30"],
        'date2' : [np.nan, np.nan, "2021-06-30", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-30"]
    })
    
>>> data
    
    date1       date2
0   NaN         NaN
1   NaN         NaN
2   2021-05-26  2021-06-30
3   2021-06-25  2021-06-28
4   2021-06-30  2021-06-30
```

Thus I am trying to ignore the rows with NaN values when creating the new column with the delay. I am using a list comprehension to do it, with an if condition to have another value (here 0) instead of the NaNs.

But my list comprehension doesn't seem to work, as the same error occurs, saying the method can't deal with NaNs. Then it seems I didn't achieve to ignore the NaNs with my if condition... But I don't know how to do it.

I am using the method : `pd.bdate_range()`

```
data["delay"] = [len(pd.bdate_range(x,y)) for x,y in zip(data.date1,\
                                    data.date2) if (x,y) != np.isnan]


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...

ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT
```

I tried adding an else condition but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe.

Comment: Just did it sir

Comment: Were you helped by my answer? Go ahead and accept it if so, that way your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `if (x,y) != np.isnan` does not do what you think it does. Firstly, `np.isnan` is a function, so you are performing an equality check of a tuple of datetimes against a function reference. Secondly, `np.nan == np.nan` is `False` -- don't do equality comparisons on `NaN` objects, filter your dataframe for `NaN` first, then *apply* your function (don't use a comprehension):

```py
mask = ~df.isnull().any(axis=1)
df["delay"] = df[mask].apply(lambda r: len(pd.bdate_range(r.date1, r.date2)), axis=1)
```

If any rows had `NaT`, they will be `NaN` in the `delay` column.